# Why does celery worker keep trying to connect to amqp even though the broker is sqs?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-sqs

I tried to configure broker via settings and directly from the celery file .
Settings that apply to celery below.

```
AWS_SQS_SECRET = os.environ.get("AWS_SQS_SECRET")

broker_url = 'sqs://%s:%s@' % (AWS_SQS_ACCESS, AWS_SQS_SECRET)

task_default_queue = os.environ.get("DEFAULT_QUEUE")


AWS_SQS_REGION = os.environ.get("AWS_REGION")


broker_backend = "SQS"
broker_transport_options = {
    "region": AWS_SQS_REGION,
    # 'queue_name_prefix': '%s-' % 'dev' , # os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'),
    'visibility_timeout': 7200,
    'polling_interval': 1,
 
}
accept_content = ['application/json']
result_serializer = 'json'
task_serializer = 'json'
```

Also, as I mentioned, I tried to configure directly from the celery file.

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.conf import settings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyApp.settings')

AWS_SQS_ACCESS = os.environ.get("AWS_SQS_ACCESS")
AWS_SQS_SECRET = os.environ.get("AWS_SQS_SECRET")

app = Celery('MyApp') #,, broker='sqs://%s:%s@' % (AWS_SQS_ACCESS, AWS_SQS_SECRET), backend='django-db'
# app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings') #, namespace='CELERY'

CELERY_CONFIG = {
    "CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT": ["json"],
    "CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND": None,
    "CELERY_TIMEZONE": "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "CELERY_ENABLE_UTC": True,
    "CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL": False,
}

BROKER_URL = 'sqs://%s:%s@' % (AWS_SQS_ACCESS, AWS_SQS_SECRET)

CELERY_CONFIG.update(
    **{
        "BROKER_URL": BROKER_URL,
        "BROKER_TRANSPORT": "sqs",
        "BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS": {
            "region": "sa-east-1",
            "visibility_timeout": 3600,
            "polling_interval": 60,
        },
    }
)

app.conf.update(**CELERY_CONFIG)

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

During deployment on elastik beanstalk , in the service I am running the command:

```
$PYTHONPATH/celery -A celery worker -Q default-dev -n default-worker \
         --logfile=/var/log/celery/celery-stdout-error.log --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=1
```

Tried to run before:

```
$PYTHONPATH/celery -A MyApp worker -Q default-dev -n default-worker \
         --logfile=/var/log/celery/celery-stdout-error.log --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=1
```

But getting error , celery "unable to load app MyApp".

In the log file I get the following error:

```
[2022-06-10 15:58:25,678: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 6.00 seconds... (3/100)
```

My celery version is 5.2.7

Comment: Since it can't load the MyApp, it will try all the defaults. Reason why it is "unable to load app MyApp" is typically because it is in wrong path.

Comment: @DejanLekic before that I used celery 4, and broker redis, there were no problems when running -A/ --app MyApp , then I updated the version to 5.2.7 and ran as indicated in the documentation https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application , there tasks is equivalent to my celery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you face the same issue , just try to restart your celery services.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the [configuration docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings) [correctly](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings), we're supposed to set config as follows:

```
app.conf.broker_url = BROKER_URL
# or, alternatively
app.conf.update(broker_url=BROKER_URL)
```

i.e., use the lowercase names instead of the uppercase names.